# Why won't file stay selected after form post?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I am trying to allow an image to be uploaded with a form.  I have code that makes sure that the user has entered valid information into the form.  If invalid information is submitted, the user is asked to correct the errors and submit the form again.  I am using the post data to populate the form fields so that the user does not have to enter the information again and is able to just edit the information they have already entered.  It seems that the $_POST is receiving the file information but it will change to displaying "No file selected." rather than the name of the file.  What is the problem here?  Below are some excerpts of my code

```
//Set field values as posted data.
if ($_FILES["Image"]["error"] > 0) 
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["Image"]["error"] . "<br>";
} 
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["Image"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["Image"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["Image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"];
}
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Image = $_FILES["Image"];
```

And the form:

```
<td><input type="file" name="Image" value="<?php echo($_FILES["Image"]["name"]); ?>"></td>
```

Comment: Because it's a security risk if you could pre-select a file. For example you could pre-select a sensible file and simply hide the upload field through css.

Comment: Hmm, then I have to wonder how websites show a preview thumbnail of say, an avatar someone is uploading to a forum.  as it does get uploaded, I imagine I could display the image to them but if I am using the form action as the page itself, the image will be uploaded multiple times if the user enters any invalid information.

Comment: I'd at least like to show a preview when the file is selected as opposed to just the file name.  Is this achievable through PHP or would I be required to use client side scripting?

Comment: If all your validation is server-side, then even if the validation fails for a field, the file upload would still take place. You could then store the file temporarily and use it if no new file gets uploaded.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to make me think that regardless of a file upload it might be a better idea to validate client side so the form only gets submitted once.  On a highly trafficked website with a registration form this could save resources.

Comment: Never do validation **only** on the client side. For you do not know if the data will really be sent through your formular.

Comment: To be honest, I seldom do. I only truly validate on the server. On the client side it's a usability feature which has to be paid extra. ;)

Comment: sorry I deleted that last comment before I noticed you had responded.  Yea I assumed it's better to do and easier to do server side but then I got the idea that very highly trafficked websites might do it client side to save resources.  I guess I'll stick with server side for now.  I do notice some websites doing certain things client side so it's live and the user isn't able to submit the form unless all fields are valid. That would be pretty nice but I wonder then if there's any server side going on that I'm just not imagining.

Comment: Well it's a matter of how much effort should be put in. Basically you absolutely have to validate server side. But to have a more responsive client side, you could pre-validate before the data get's submitted. But to reduce the amount of work, in this case. I would try to keep it simple. Let the server just refuse invalid requests. And submit the form through ajax instead of a traditional *form-post-request*. If these topics are new to you, then you'll have some reading to do. ;)

Comment: Oh yes, I'm intermediate-advanced in php. Inexperienced, at best, in JavaScript, and If I had to guess, Ajax is something similar to JQuery,  so that tells you how much I know about that topic. Haha.

Comment: Ok then, if you're new to many of these things, I'd suggest to keep it simple. Stick to php and server-side validation. Store the uploaded file somewhere temporarily and keep note of it in a session. This way the user does not have to upload it again if validation fails. Regarding the high-traffic of this form, never pre-optimize. Do this only when there is a real problem.